# File logging in cloud Haskell using monad-logger

Tags: haskell, logging, monad-transformers, cloud-haskell

I am trying to log into a file from inside Cloud Haskell's [processes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process-0.6.6/docs/Control-Distributed-Process.html#t:Process). In order to do so I have been using the [monad-logger](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-logger-0.3.24) library which exposes [runFileLoggingT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-logger-0.3.24/docs/Control-Monad-Logger.html#v:runFileLoggingT). The code I'm using looks like:

```
mainProcess :: Process ProcessId
mainProcess = spawnLocal $ runFileLoggingT "log/application.log" $ return ()
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Could not deduce (Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl
>                             IO Process)

That is because **runFileLoggingT** has to work on a monad that implements [MonadBaseControl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl), which is not the case for **Process**. Being a beginner on monad transformers I don't know how to implement the instance myself.

What do I need to do in order to make it work?

Comment: Have you looked at the section of the page you linked entitled [Defaults](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#g:4)? You should begin by copying the code there, replacing `B` with `Process`. (Note that "I don't know how to X" is not a good question format for SO. You should include what you've tried and why it didn't work, or at least what you misunderstand)